# Trouble editing text files with powershell Get-Content and Set-Content

Tags: powershell, pipe

Goal: Update text entry on one line within many files distributed on a server
Summary: As part of an application migration between datacenters the .rdp files on end-user desktops need to be updated to point to the new IP address of their Remote Desktop Server. All the .rdp files reside on Windows servers in a redirected folders SMB share where I have Administrative access.

Powershell experience: minimal. Still trying to wrap my head around the way variables, output and piping work.

Was originally trying to make a single line of powershell code to complete this task but got stuck and had to make script file with the two lines of code below.
-Line 1: Search for all .rdp files in the folder structure and store the full path with file name in a variable. Every file will be checked since the users tend to accidentally change file names, eliminating absolute predictability.
-Line 2: I want to make one pass through all the files to replace only instances of two particular IP addresses with the new address. Then write the changes into the original file.

```
$Path = ls 'C:\Scripts\Replace-RDP\TESTFILES\' -Include *.rdp -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | foreach fullname
$Path | (Get-Content -Path $Path) -Replace 'IPserver1','newIPserver1' -Replace 'IPserver2','newIPserver2' | Set-Content $Path -Force
```

Have found most of the solution with Powershell but have a problem with the results. The second line of code when output to the screen changes contents correctly in memory. The content written to file however resulted in the new server IP address being written into ALL rdp files even if the source rdp file's target IP address doesn't match the -Replace criterion.

Text inside a .rdp on the relevant line is:
full address:s:192.168.1.123
changes to:
full address:s:172.16.1.23

Thank you for all assistance in reaching the endpoint. Have spent hours learning from various sites and code snippets.

Comment: Your second line is not valid PowerShell, you can't have arbitrary value expression (like `(Get-Content ...) replace '...'`) in the middle of the pipeline. Please update with your actual code

Comment: Why not use a DNS name in the .rdp files? Then you just update the DNS record and don't have to change the .rdp files.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Management doesn't want to use DNS records which he considers to be a security risk. Event if I could change to FQDN I'd still need this script to change all the .rdp files.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen That was all the code I had in the script. Line 2 did work correctly through the first pipe with output displaying in the powershell console.

Comment: DNS records are a security risk? Does the internet know about this?

Comment: -amused- My boss thinks that that by making manual DNS entries in a client's local domain DNS for the private cloud target, a virus/malware might read the entire zone contents and attempt a spread from client domain/network to the cloud/IT service network. So he concludes that the convenience isn't worth the risk.

Comment: Amused by the response, FWIW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep track of each file that you are reading so that you can save changes to that file. `Foreach-Object` makes this process easy. Inside of the `Foreach-Object` script block, the current object `$_` is the `FullName` value for each of your files.

```
$CurrentIP1 = '192\.168\.1\.123'
$CurrentIP2 = '192\.168\.1\.124'
$NewIP1 = '172.16.1.23'
$NewIP2 = '172.16.1.24'

$files = (Get-ChildItem 'C:\Scripts\Replace-RDP\TESTFILES\' -Filter *.rdp -Recurse -Force -File -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).FullName
$files | Foreach-Object {
    if (($contents = Get-Content $_) -match "$CurrentIP1|$CurrentIP2") {
        $contents -replace $CurrentIP1,$NewIP1 -replace $CurrentIP2,$NewIP2 |
            Set-Content $_
    }
}
```

Note that using the `-File` switch on `Get-ChildItem` (alias `ls`) outputs only files. Since `-replace` uses regex to do matching, you must backslash escape literal `.` characters.

Comment: this script update works correctly and quickly. I appreciate the adjustments for handling the variables that make the code easier to read, removing the extra pipe in line 1, and teaching me the correct way to pass the filename into the loop with the $_ object

After running the test I see the file timestamps are all changed even if there was no material change to a file. How can the current loop iteration be exited if neither $CurrentIP1 nor $CurrentIP2 are found?

What is the reason the two currentIP variables need the \ escape character but the NewIP variables do not?

Comment: I added a version to only update files that contain the IPs.